# can't type continuously on text box

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead, twitter-typeahead

I add bootstrap typeahead function to JSP text box. for

https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=typeahead-with-local-dataset

It works. but I can't type continuously with in text box. I can type only one character per one time. If i want to add another character i need to click with in the text box. Then type another character.

Here is my code..

```
$("#tagText").bind("keyup", function (event){
     event.preventDefault();
     var tagSuggest = $("#tagText").val();
     var url= "../operation/SuggestSupport!searchSuggest.action?documentTag.tagText="+tagSuggest+"&page=0&activePage=0";
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: url,
         dataType:"json",
         success: function(data){
         var cars = $.map(data, function(el) { return el });
         // Constructing the suggestion engine
         var cars = new Bloodhound({
          datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
          queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
          local: cars
      });

      // Initializing the typeahead
      $("#tagText").typeahead({
          hint: false,
          highlight: true, /* Enable substring highlighting */
          minLength: 1 /* Specify minimum characters required for showing result */
      },
      {
      name: 'cars',
      source: cars
      );

      },
      error: function (data){
     alert("Error");
     }
     });
});
```

And this is my text box.

```
<div class="input-group">
     <s:textfield name="document.tagText" id="tagText" cssClass="form-control" maxlength="100" autocomplete="off" style="width: 237px; border-radius: 4px;"/> 
</div>
```

Comment: because you add ajax call when keyup so need time to finish ajax call

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_blur_alert

Comment: Ok I will refer, thanks

Comment: I'm new to this subject, I cant imagine how to do this exactly @ShafiqulIslam

Comment: just change $("#tagText").bind("keyup", function (event){ to
$("#tagText").bind("blur", function (event){

then check , first read about blur function

Comment: You didn't get my point.. I need to execute function when the key up. I need to add another function when the success has data..

Comment: when I use blur, even my function is not working. previously it works

Comment: $( "#tagText" ).blur(function() {
  // your code here
});

Comment: you mean should I need to use $( "#tagText" ).blur(function() { // your code here });  instead of $("#tagText").bind("keyup", function (event){ ----------   It's not working----  My function is already work. the problem is once I type one key, I can see suggestion. but tex box is disabled